# Chromedriver.exe hangs at the end of Intern.js script Chrome 76 /ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.25

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, intern

I am facing one issue: after my functional tests finish, the browser closes, but chromedriver.exe stays running, leading to multiple instances of chromedriver.exe .

I have automated project which internally calls Intern, at the end all processes started by intern must be destroyed else result of our test will KO . But since in some cases it hangs chromedriver.exe after functional test finishes we get KO result

I am using intern 3.1.1 (it's our projects requirement), Chrome version 76 and ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.25.

I have tried modifying tunnel.js

```
    childProcess.kill('SIGINT');
            kill(childProcess.pid);
```

still same behavior..

tried taskkill 1.2 and 3

also tried

```
    setTimeout(function() {
       childProcess.kill('SIGINT');
               },
       100);
```

still same behavior.

what i need to change so that chromedriver closes automatically at the end of script execution

Thank You

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am wind Windows 7 and windows 10 operating system

Answer (score 0):

Intern (really digdug) kills Selenium when a test session finishes, but (particularly on Windows) that doesn't always end up killing any started chromedrivers.

Dig Dug v2 deals with that by [explicitly killing the immediate children](https://github.com/theintern/digdug/blob/master/src/lib/util.ts#L40-L80) of the Selenium process as well as the process itself.

You could do something similar in a custom version of digdug, around [here](https://github.com/theintern/digdug/blob/1.5.0/SeleniumTunnel.js#L363).